# Parametric Volume

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions, 3d-printing

How can one write a function `VolumeParametricPlot` achieving the effect of a `ParametricPlot3D` with three parametrising variables, so as to create a plot of a volume rather than a surface?

As a simple example:

```
VolumeParametricPlot[
  {x,y,(x^2+y^2-1/6 y^3)+h},
  {x,-5,5},
  {y,-5,5},
  {h,-0.2,0.2}
]
```

[image]

---

### Additional information:

`RegionPlot3D` won't work for the general problem, and is also quite slow because of its implementation. I am looking for something to behave in the same way as `ParametricPlot3D`, except with three parametrising variables instead of only two.

Comment: What about `ParametricPlot3D[{x, y, (x^2 + y^2 - 1/6 y^3)}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.6}, PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.2]]`?

Comment: and `ParametricPlot3D[{x, y, (x^2 + y^2 - 1/6 y^3)}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 
  5}, BoxRatios -> 1, Extrusion -> .4]`?

Comment: I am looking for something to behave in the same way as `ParametricPlot3D`.

Comment: if speed is not an issue you can use `ParametricRegion` + `DiscretizeRegion`. E.g., `parreg = ParametricRegion[{x, y, 
    h + (x^2 + y^2 - 1/6 y^3)}, {{x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {h, -1, 1}}];
DiscretizeRegion[parreg, 
 Method -> {"MarchingCubes", PlotPoints -> 150}]`

Comment: This question is perfectly well defined. It should not have been closed. What more can I say?

Comment: @kglr - I can't get your example to run to completion. It crashes Mathematica.

Comment: What if you try randomly sampling points in your input, applying the function, then meshing like this: `f[x_, y_, h_] := {x, y, (x^2 + y^2 - 1/6 y^3) + h}
pts = f @@@ 
   RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}, {-0.2, 0.2}}],
     10000];
ListPointPlot3D[pts, BoxRatios -> 1]
DelaunayMesh[pts]`

Answer (score 3):

You can post-process polygon primitives into polyhedra with the desired height:

```
ClearAll[toPolyhedron]
toPolyhedron[h_][p : Polygon[coords_, VertexColors -> colors_, ___]] :=
  Module[{prt = Partition[coords, 2, 1, 1], assoc = AssociationThread[coords, colors]}, 
    Join[Translate[p, {0, 0, # h/2}] & /@ {-1, 1}, 
     Polygon[Join @@ MapIndexed[TranslationTransform[{0, 0, (-1)^#2[[1]] h/2}] /@ # &, 
       {#, Reverse@#}], VertexColors -> assoc /@ Join[# , Reverse[#]]] & /@ prt]]
```

***Examples:***

```
pplt = ParametricPlot3D[{x, y, (x^2 + y^2 - 1/6 y^3)}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
   Mesh -> None, BoxRatios -> 1, 
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Lighting -> "Neutral", 
   ImageSize -> 400, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05]];

Row[{pplt, Normal[pplt] /. p_Polygon :> toPolyhedron[10][p]}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

```
Show[Normal[pplt] /. p_Polygon :> toPolyhedron[30][p], 
 ParametricPlot3D[{x, y, (x^2 + y^2 - 1/6 y^3)}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5},
   Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black]], 
 PlotRangePadding -> {Scaled[.05], Scaled[0.05], Scaled[.15]}, 
 Lighting -> "Neutral", ImageSize -> Large, BoxRatios -> 1]
```

[image]

**Update:** As an alternative to post-processing, you can use the option [`DisplayFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DisplayFunction.html) to get the desired result in a single step:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{x, y, (x^2 + y^2 - 1/6 y^3)}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
 Mesh -> None, BoxRatios -> 1, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 Lighting -> "Neutral", ImageSize -> Large, 
 BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black], 
 PlotRangePadding -> {Scaled[.05], Scaled[0.05], Scaled[.15]}, 
 DisplayFunction -> (Normal[#] /. p_Polygon :> toPolyhedron[30][p] &)]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I used this for the point cloud to `Image3D` conversion: https://www.wolfram.com/language/gallery/make-a-3d-image-from-a-point-cloud
We generate a million points from the domain `{x,y,h}`, apply `f` and voxelize the point cloud by bin-counting. I've used a more complicated function to showcase the general problem. I don't know how to get axes on the `Image3D` however:

```
PointCloudToImage3D[points_, thresh_, slices_] := 
 Block[{ranges, bins, binCounts, transposedBinCounts}, 
  ranges = Round[{Min[#], Max[#]} & /@ Transpose[points]];
  bins = Append[#, ((#[[2]] - #[[1]])/slices)] & /@ ranges;
  binCounts = BinCounts[points, Sequence @@ bins];
  transposedBinCounts = 
   Map[UnitStep[# - thresh] &, 
    Reverse[Transpose[binCounts, {3, 2, 1}], {1, 2}], {3}];
  ImageAdjust@Image3D[Ceiling@transposedBinCounts]]
f[x_, y_, h_] := {x^2 - y^2, h y/4., x h}
pts = f @@@ 
   RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}], 
    1000000];
ListPointPlot3D[RandomSample[pts, 5000], 
 BoxRatios -> 1] (* show reduced point count*)
Image3D[PointCloudToImage3D[pts, 1, 50], BoxRatios -> 1]
```

[image: listplot and voxelized points]

Comment: "I don't know how to get axes on the `Image3D` however" - use `Raster3D[]` instead so you can put it in `Graphics3D[]`.